# xml document read having 0x19 hex character

Tags: c#, hex, xmldocument

Reading xml document with hex 0x19 character C#

Apparently the above character is invalid in C# and the XML document I am about to load contains it.

Therefore it throws XML exception everytime I try to read it.

```
<description><![CDATA[Whenever I run<br>Whenever I run to you lost one<br>Its never done<br>Just hanging on<br><br>Just past has let me be<br>Returning as if dream<br>Shattered as belief<br><br>If you have to go dont say goodbye<br>If you have to go dont you cry<br>If you have to go I will get by<br>Someday Ill follow you and see you on the other side<br><br>But for the grace of love<br>Id will the meaning of<br>Heaven from above<br><br>Your picture out of time<br>Left aching in my mind<br>Shadows kept alive<br><br>If you have to go dont say goodbye<br>If you have to go dont you cry<br>If you have to go I will get by<br>I will follow you and see you on the other side<br><br>But for the grace of love<br>Id will the meaning of<br>Heaven from above<br><br>Long horses we are born<br>Creatures more than torn<br>Mourning our way home]]></description>
```

Apparently the above line contains that character

Comment: Do you have control over how the XML is generated?  If so, either remove the illegal character or wrap it in CDATA.  Posting the XML would help us help you.

Comment: Are you sure it's that line?  That line looks valid.  Can you post more of the XML document?

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem. 0x19 is a control-character (End of Medium) which is pretty much invisible with text editors. What I did to parse the XML anyway was to replace this char with a space before parsing, like this:

```
var xmlString = GetXmlString();
xmlString = xmlString.Replace((char)0x19, ' ');
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
```

Comment: strange. Just encountered this same character but the xml string is written only by my code, and this character appeared in between two attributes in just one record the other day, supposedly (per customer) after upgrade from Oracle 11g to 12c. That sounds weird. Does Oracle or .NET ever inject that character into a large XML string for some reason?